# Wordpress post count for category including trashed

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I've got this working nicely but I need to do something similar on another template. This code lists all the categories and shows how many posts are contained in each:

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('exclude=1&order=DESC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>

<div class="cats">
<h2><a href="<?php echo $cat->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a></h2>
<p>There are <?php echo $cat->category_count; ?> posts in this category.</p>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

Now what I need to do is the same thing but the numbers output need to also include the posts that have been trashed.

Taking just one category as an example - let's call it 'Phones', let's say it has 5 published posts and 3 trashed posts, then the number returned would need to be 8.

I hope I explained that properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that hard, however, you have to go about it in a slightly different way.

In foreach you should call either `get_posts` or `WP_Query`, to grab all the posts in a particular category with customized parameter `post_status`; then dispaly count of it.

In `WP_Query` you might use

```
['post_status' => array('publish', 'trash', 'inherit', ...)]
```

`get_posts` as

```
('post_status=any&categor=1&...')
```

**EDIT**

Here is a way, how to accomplish that.

```
<?php
$categories = get_categories('exclude=1&order=DESC');
foreach ($categories as $cat) {

$posts = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => array('trash', 'publish'), 'cat' => $cat->cat_ID));?>

    <div class="cats">
        <h2><a href="<?php echo $cat->category_nicename; ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a></h2>
        <p>There are <?php echo $posts->post_count; ?> posts in this category.</p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand that. Would you show me with a complete example?

Comment: Perfect except for one small problem - it seems to be not counting about 10. The categories that have less than 10 posts (trashed and published combined) show the correct number, all the other categories that have more than 10 posts (trashed and published combined) seems to only show the number 10.

What could be causing that?

Comment: EDIT: I fixed it by adding

     'showposts' => -1

Thanks again dude!

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = $wpdb -> get_results("SELECT count(*) as count 
FROM `wp_posts`, `wp_term_relationships`
WHERE id=object_id AND term_taxonomy_id=$cat_id AND post_type='post' AND 
post_status='publish'");
$count = $count[0] -> count;
```